# Lisp, Remove sublist with two common elements

Tags: lisp

i am programming in Common lisp, and i need an algorithm that delete sublist with (at least) two common elements.

i don't have any idea to how i can solve the problem. I thought to use this:

(defun remove-duplicates-list (list) (remove-duplicates list :test 'equal :key 'cdr))

but the cdr between the sublists is different, and i just can't figure out how i can count two elements and remove the sublist.
Also i need to don't remove the "original" sublist (in the example '(1 2 3 4)), bot only (2 3 4) and (1 3 4)

Example :

input: '( (1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (1 3 4) (9 9 9 9) )

output: '( (1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (9 9 9 9) )

input: '( ((1 . 1) (2 . 2) (3 . 3) (4 . 4)) ((1 . 1) (2 . 2) (4 . 4)))

output : '((1 . 1) (2 . 2) (3 . 3) (4 . 4))

Thank you!

P.s sorry if, at first, i have not explained well my problem, i correct many mistake in the post. this is my first question on this community, so forgive please

Comment: From the Stackoverflow help: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: yes, thank u, so far i have complete my project, i have the only difficult to write an algorithm for this. It is easy, but i am stuck. i will add now more example

Comment: Have you tried your code? What happened?

Comment: my code compares the cdr/rest of the various sublist, but as can you see the cdr/rest of the sublist change. So my code(the fuction remove-duplicate-list) is totally wrong. I need a code to found sublist shorter than "original" (in example the original sublist is '(1 2 3 4)) and with at least two elements that are also in "original" sublist.

Comment: so in the first example i need to found the sublists (2 3 4) and (1 3 4) and remove them, because they have two elements in common with (1 2 3 4).

Comment: Have you tried your code? What happened?

Comment: my code(the fuction remove-duplicate-list) return null. In one of my comment i have explained why.

Comment: that's not possible, it can't return NIL. The code you wrote returns `CDR`. Just the symbol `CDR`.  Always.

Comment: i just correct the function above in the post. Trough remove-duplicate-list i have implemented the remove-duplicates function (a default fuction of lisp). sorry for the mistake

Comment: Now the function always gives an error. You still haven't tried to run it. ;-) How about reading some nice Lisp introduction instead? Download the book as PDF for free: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: okay, today is not my day. i was very quickly and i just do an error to read and write here my function. i will do now a copy and paste, i think that is more easy. (defun remove-duplicate-sublist (List) (remove-duplicates List :test #'equal :key 'cdr))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could do it with `remove-duplicates`. You need to make a test function that returns true when at least two elements are similar. eg.

```
(defun two-similar-p (lst1 lst2)
  ...)

(two-similar-p '(1 2 3) '(1 4 5)) ; ==> nil
(two-similar-p '(1 2 5) '(1 4 5)) ; ==> t
```

Using a hash is the fastest and best time complexity while iterating one list `(length other-list)` times is possibly the easiest. Then you can solve your problem this way:

```
(defun remove-duplicates-list (list) 
  (remove-duplicates list :test #'two-similar-p :from-end t))

(remove-duplicates-list '((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (1 3 4) (9 9 9 9)))
; ==> ((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (9 9 9 9))
```

Comment: i will try to write the code for this function (two-similar-p), thank you for your answer. If i have any problem i will update this post or maybe i will write a comment here